# What is a Hessian matrix?

Tags: calculus, hessian-matrix

I know that the Hessian matrix is a kind of second derivative test of functions involving more than one independent variable. How does one find the maximum or minimum of a function involving more than one variable? Is it found using the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix or its principal minors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test

For an n-dimensional function *f*, find an *x* where the gradient grad *f* = 0. This is a critical point.

Then, the 2nd derivatives tell, whether *x* marks a local minimum, a maximum or a saddle point.

The Hessian *H* is the matrix of all combinations of 2nd derivatives of *f*.

1. For the 2D-case the determinant and the minors of the Hessian are relevant.
2. For the nD-case it might involve a computation of eigen values of the Hessian *H* (if *H* is invertible) as part of checking *H* for being positive (or negative) definite.

In fact, the shortcut in 1) is generalized by 2)

For numeric calculations, some kind of optimization strategy can be used for finding *x* where grad *f* = 0.

Comment: Can you please correct this explanation to make the equations appear as equations and not as a supposedly latex code. I am finding it difficult to follow the equations .